# "Disease X is allelic with disease Y" - what is the meaning of "allelic" here?

Tags: genetics

From a review on Cerebral Folate Deficiency:

> A disorder initially reported as folinic acid responsive epilepsy was subsequently shown to be **allelic with** PDE – both are caused by biallelic mutations in ALDH7A1 (Gallagher et al, 2009).

Does it mean that the same exact mutation causes both diseases, and they are fully identical? I think it means that, but I'm not 100% sure, so I decided to ask here.

Since by allele we mean "a variant form of a given gene" this must be the term to indicate that two diseases previously considered different are in fact fully identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Humpath.com](https://www.humpath.com/spip.php?article1120), allelic diseases are **two different diseases caused by mutations of the same gene.**

Two or more different errors at the same gene can result in two or more different diseases.

Examples:

- The mentioned folinic acid-responsive epilepsy and pyridoxine-dependent epilepsy ([NCBI Gene Reviews](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK1486/))
- Noonan syndrome and LEOPARD syndrome ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC379170/))
- Cowden Syndrome and Bannayan-Riley-Ruvalcaba Syndrome ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2886463/))
- Muckle-Wells syndrome, CINCA syndrome and familial cold urticaria ([Orphanet](https://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/OC_Exp.php?Lng=GB&Expert=47045))

Comment: So it could be two different alleles (variations of the same gene) causing two diseases with slightly different clinical profiles? Interesting. Judging by the name alone, I thought it meant "the very same allele". Now I'll think how to translate this into Russian..

Comment: Yes, they are different alleles - the variations of the same gene.